# ruby on rails Models Schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello every one I'm new to ruby on rails. I go through the following code in which I'm told that database schema is being loaded through this code:

```
Account.current = Question.find(2)
Question.last
```

I'm unable to understand about how schema is being loaded. what this code is actually doing. Please help

Comment: Not sure what you have going on in those models but from the code it looks like you are calling the `current=` class method on `Account` and passing it an instance of the `Question` model. `Question.last` will retrieve the last row from the `questions` table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Rails Guides (Active Record). Here is the [documentation.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

Also, look at AREL. Here is the link to it on [GitHub](https://github.com/rails/arel).

This [article](http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/9/23/how-arel-converts-ruby-queries-into-sql-statements) explains how arel converts ruby queries into sql statements.